# Does a constant 0 function have simple zeros?

Tags: real-analysis

Maybe this is a stupid question, but assume we have constant function $f=0$. Then my simple question is if this function has simple zeros?

Any element in the domain is a zero of infinite multiplicity, isn' it?

Comment: What is simple zero of a function? If you mean a zero such that it is not a zero of derivative then of course all zeros of identical zero function are not simple.

Comment: Can the multiplicity of a zero be greater than the degree of the polynomial? (If we're not considering $f$ as a polynomial, what does multiplicity of zeros mean?)